# Having Issue with Clearfix Class

Tags: css, clearfix

Can you please take a look my webpage(contact page) and let me know why still I am having this issue whit clearfix class? I even used the clear both on all elements but still this is happening! and tghe #bizleft and #bizright are not aligned!

http://ghazalphoto.com/contact/

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you want to post some code instead of making people dig.. however. [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hDnjg/1/)

Remove the clear: both on the #bizleft & #bizright

```
#bizleft{
    float:left;  
    width:49%; 
}
#bizright{
    width:49%;  
    float:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add below code to your `#bizright` class

```
position: absolute;
right: 10px;
```